# aix java core zero size

Tags: java, jvm, aix, ulimit, core-file

in my AIX 6.1 ,java 1.5.0

```
bash-3.2$ java -fullversion
java full version "J2RE 1.5.0 IBM AIX build pap32devifx-20080811c (SR8a)"
bash-3.2$
```

i am getting core by running java . but i see the size of core file is zero. i set 
ulimit -c unlimited and here below are deatils

```
-rw-r--r--    1 vyellepe rdl           54763 Sep 23 08:43 management_demo_client.log

-rwx------    1 root     system            0 Sep 23 08:43 core.20110923.084309.1339644.dmp

bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) 1048575
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 32768
open files                      (-n) 2000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 64
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 32768
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
bash-3.2$
```

can you help what needed to be set to get the core file

Comment: Why is that core file owned by `root`?

Answer (score 0):

Not too much versed about ulimit on AIX, but seems memory limit:

```
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 32768
```

Seems not sufficient for Java JVM, so try increasing it. Typical JVM memory for a production server could stert at 512MB. [Post](http://www.unix.com/aix/125392-aix-6-1-kernal-parameters-ulimit.html) about problem with memory limit in AIX 6.1 after rebooting.